Indexing in mongoose using Nestjs framwork
How to create index/ best way to create index in nestJS schema
@Schema({ _id: true, timestamps: true, collection: 'diagnoses' })
export class Diagnosis {
  /**
   * ID of the associated device.
   */
  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId })
  _id: Types.ObjectId;

  /**
   * ICD-10 code for the diagnosis.
   */
  @Prop({ type: String })
  icd_10_code: string;

  /**
   * Name of the diagnosis.
   */
  @Prop({ type: String })
  name: string;

  /**
   * Type of diagnosis (from DiagnosisTypeEnum).
   */
  @Prop({ type: String, enum: Object.values(DiagnosisTypeEnum) })
  type: DiagnosisTypeEnum;

  /**
   * ID of the associated device.
   */
  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'patients', index: true })
  _patient_id: Types.ObjectId;

  /**
   * ID of the associated person who created it.
   */
  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId })
  _created_by: Types.ObjectId;

  /**
   * List of past devices (Devices interface).
   */
  @Prop({ type: [Device] })
  devices: Device[];

  /**
   * List of past devices (Devices interface).
   */
  @Prop({ type: [String], default: [] })
  expectedDevices: string[];

  /**
   * Flag for logical deletion.
   */
  @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: false })
  is_deleted: boolean;
}

/**
 * Generates the Mongoose schema for the Diagnosis class.
 */
export const DiagnosisSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Diagnosis);

DiagnosisSchema.index({ _patient_id: 1 });

As I put index: true in prop decorator
OR This is better
DiagnosisSchema.index({ _patient_id: 1 });
